# dbeaver export wont include scriptFilename

Tags: sql, export-to-csv, dbeaver

**First SQL question, so probably written badly.**

I want to

- use export from query to -> create tasks
- use task to -> export easily 5 tables.

I want to use scriptFilename to identify the exported table, with name:

```
trial_${scriptFilename}_${date}
```

[image]

- It works if I DONT create task, and just press 'proceed'
- If i create a task and then run the task, it ignores scriptfilename.

How do I save the files using taks with Scriptfilename?
Or if not possible,
What is a better solution to:

- Export data from 5 sql scripts in an easy way.
  I am probably doing something silly and missing the obvious way of getting data from a PostgreSQL online database to python pands...

Comment: I can't see how this is related to the SQL _language_,

Comment: @jarlh I am trying to export tables generated with SQL (getting data with Dbeaver). Not sure if it belongs here or in another Forum. I am guessing that I am missing a solution related to SQL, like exporting tables by concatenating all SQL scripts and then have an SQL command like 'Save all tables to csv'

Comment: 'Save all tables to csv' is not SQL.